# How to group based on the color, size and style

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, group-by

```
[{
  boxNoFrom: 1,
  boxs: [{…}],
  color: "ESPRESSO",
  size: "2X",
  style: "ZIP UP"
{
  boxNoFrom: 13,
  boxs: [{…}],
  color: "ESPRESSO",
  size: "2X",
  style: "ZIP UP"
},
{
  boxNoFrom: 14,
  boxs: [{…}],
  color: "ESPRESSO",
  size: "2X",
  style: "ZIP UP"
},
{
  boxNoFrom: 22,
  boxs: [{…}],
  color: "ESPRESSO",
  size: "3X"
  style: "ZIP UP"
},
{
  boxNoFrom: 178,
  boxs: [{…}],
  color: "ESPRESSO",
  size: "XXL"
  style: "ZIP UP"
},
{
  boxNoFrom: 198,
  boxs: [{…}],
  color: "ESPRESSO",
  size: "XXS",
  style: "ZIP UP"
},
{
  boxNoFrom: 206,
  boxs: [{…}],
  color: "ESPRESSO",
  size: "2X",
  style: "ZIP UP"
},
{
  boxNoFrom: 203,
  boxs: [{…}],
  color: "ESPRESSO",
  size: "XXS",
  style: "ZIP UP"
}]
```

How to group the data based on the `color/size/style`
for example it will group the same color and same size and style. the `boxNoFrom 206` should be place after the `boxNoFrom 14` and the `boxNoFrom 203` will be place after `boxNoFrom: 198`.
Where it will be like this.

```
  [{
      boxNoFrom: 1,
      boxs: [{…}],
      color: "ESPRESSO",
      size: "2X",
      style: "ZIP UP"
    {
      boxNoFrom: 13,
      boxs: [{…}],
      color: "ESPRESSO",
      size: "2X",
      style: "ZIP UP"
    },
    {
      boxNoFrom: 14,
      boxs: [{…}],
      color: "ESPRESSO",
      size: "2X",
      style: "ZIP UP"
    },
    {
      boxNoFrom: 206,
      boxs: [{…}],
      color: "ESPRESSO",
      size: "2X",
      style: "ZIP UP"
    }
    {
      boxNoFrom: 22,
      boxs: [{…}],
      color: "ESPRESSO",
      size: "3X"
      style: "ZIP UP"
    },
    {
      boxNoFrom: 178,
      boxs: [{…}],
      color: "ESPRESSO",
      size: "XXL"
      style: "ZIP UP"
    },
        {
          boxNoFrom: 203,
          boxs: [{…}],
          color: "ESPRESSO",
          size: "XXS",
          style: "ZIP UP"
        }]
```

But if there's a new `boxNoFrom` where it is same color, size and style it will be place after the `boxNoFrom` for example there's a new `boxNoFom` which `204` then it has

```
color: "ESPRESSO",
size: "2X",
style: "ZIP UP"
```

then it will be place after the `203`.

Comment: Cool. How would you go about it? I'm sure you must have tried something. It helps to see you work - it shows you're taking part in the process, not just asking people to write code for you. Your attempt may not have worked, that's ok. Its important to show it though

Comment: @Kinglish do I need to use the ```reduce```?

Comment: That is how I would go about it

Answer (score -1):

You can try using Map for this purpose.

I am using simpler information for easier understanding.

```
let arr = [
       {val:1, color: "A"},
       {val: 2, color: "B"}, 
       {val: 3, color: "A"}, 
       {val: 4, color: "B"}
]

// create a new map
let map = new Map()
// parse through the array of information
arr.forEach(_cur => {
    // initialize an empty array for current color in map(if not already present) 
    map[_cur.color] = map[_cur.color] || []
    // add the current values in the map corresponding to current color
    map[_cur.color].push(_cur) 
})

// for color "A"
console.log(map["A"])

// for color "B"
console.log(map["B"])

let order = ["B", "A"]
let arrangedInfo = []
order.map(cur => {
    // first adding previously added info, then adding elements corresponding to current color in order
    arrangedInfo = [...arrangedInfo, ...map[cur]]
})

console.log(arrangedInfo)
```

I hope this would help you!